# How to center an iframe inside list item

Tags: html, css, iframe, center

I am trying to centered the `iframe` but seems its not working.

**HTML code:**

```
<ul class ="xslides" id=xslide1">
  <li><iframe width="750px" height="500px" frameborder="0" src="test/embed" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="border: none; max-width:100%; max-height:100vh" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen  mozallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.xslides ul li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  }
```

Comment: `<ul class ="xslides" id=xslide1">` should be `<ul class ="xslides" id="xslide1">` . Do not use `width` and `height` attribute, use CSS instead.

Comment: i have edit the ID's and also remove the width and height..seems the iframe show small in small size..

Comment: i have place the src link inside frame tags, image seems link to a particular url

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to accomplish here. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

If I do not remember it incorrectly, the list item is an inline element.

```
.xslides ul li {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   width: 100%;
   display: block;

 }
 iframe {
   outline: 1px solid black;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 750px;
   height: 500px;
 }
```

You may want to try this,

https://jsfiddle.net/fpc9g3mx/

By the way you may also want to remove `list-style` for from `.xslides`.

Comment: i have tried what you said but it doesn't work, you shown CSS but the html code seems ok?..unless i placed the width and height on html code it works for the size but not centered seems it  but cant read the css

Comment: Will you draw a simple image to elaborate what you want? and update the question by putting the image inside.

Comment: the only issues is that i cannot centered it..for images it works but ifram cannot,,checking on iframe css

Comment: The image to put on webpage is save in another url but not save as an image